# How to keep zoomlevel in Evince constant after clicking a link?

Tags: pdf, default, evince, zooming

I really love how Evince works but this little thing is annoying me so much. When I select a title or a subtitle from the table of contents it shifts the zoom. On windows it was just easy as pie with Foxit but its Linux version really needs time.

Comment: "When i select a title or a subtitle from the content menu it shifts the zoom". Can you clarify this? If you mean to say that the zoom level changes when choosing a different entry in the table of contents, that works perfectly fine for me. What exactly happens when you choose an entry?

Comment: yes i always want it to be set "fit page width" but when i select a title it changes that something like "%75" and i have to re-set it to "fit page width" everytime.Save the current option did not works so far.

Comment: Yes yes thanks for asking this, just what I needed

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default sizing-mode 'fit-page'

Answer (score 51):

this should work.

open up a terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince allow-links-change-zoom false
```

Comment: No such key 'allow-links-change-zoom' .  using 12.04,  evince 3.4.0

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! There is no way to set this behavior through the Evince UI. You can save the default settings, but clicking a bookmark link upsets the same, unless you set this from `gsettings`.

Comment: Exactly this, just set it from `gsettings` and be happy

Comment: that command worked for me on Fedora 32 workstation, thanks pal. "Document Viewer" (Evince) 3.36.7

Comment: Worked for me in Pop OS 20.04. Super frustrating problem and this is the only fix I've found that works. Thanks!

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 21.10, but is there other side effects?

Comment: worked for me, Fedora 36

Answer (score 12):

To set the default zoom, you can either set it in the program and then go to edit > 'save current settings as default' or select your value and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom 1.75
```

**However**, i think what you are really referring to is when, say you have a big zoom level of 175% and you have the sidebar enabled and continuous mode enabled, scrolling to the next page upsets the zoom. This makes the page go off centre and you have to adjust it manually each time, as the first screenshot below shows.

To change this behaviour, the only real fix is to select the 'fit page width' option by going to view > 'fit page width'. Then go to edit > 'save current settings as default'. This will eliminate the issue, as the second screenshot shows, although the zoom level will drop a bit as you **can't** set a zoom level and have the 'fit page width' option enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is i know about the feature "save the current settings as default" but when I select a title crom context it just changes the zoom again.

Comment: @c.k. The 'fit page width' setting should be probably what you need.

Comment: I with with the OP.  'fit page width' + 'set current settings as default' does not resolve the issue.  I've tried this combo at least a dozen times, the zoom level is still resetting whenever evince launches, and then (more annoyingly) every time a page is selected from the sidebar/table of contents.

Comment: Agreed, does not work.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/612913/207451

Comment: @paulodiovani Thanks, this work for me.  Can't believe this bug has been around for likie 10 years now.

Answer (score 3):

Simple run `$dconf-editor` then `org/gnome/evince` or search via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> after opening the editor.
Then change the default settings `default/continuous/zoom` etc.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on using dconf. On Ubuntu 18.04, set `allow-link-change-zoom` to Off helps me avoid this zoom-changing issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be related to dconf and Evince apparmor settings. A possible solution is buried at this link:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/682492

tl;dr

1. First, install dconf-tools:

   ```
   apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Then reconfigure apparmor:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
   ```
3. Configuration will ask for the path to your home folder. Which is generally:

   ```
   /home
   ```

This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal zoom is constrained by page cache size so by setting higher value you should be able to get higher zoom:

`gsettings set org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size 300`

Worked for me.