# Configure Evince to open maximized with 100% zoom level?

Tags: 12.04, pdf, evince

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS installed on my computer.

If I open PDF in Evince for the first time, the window is always un-maximized and zoom level is 70%. I want Evince to be maximized and the zoom level set to 100% every time I open a PDF.

I have tried to adjust the settings and clicked "Save Current Settings as Default" but when I open a new PDF, Evince is un-maximized and zoom level is 70%.

How can I get Evince to open maximized and with zoom level 100%?

Comment: For zoom [see here](http://askubuntu.com/q/213820/15341).

Comment: Run with `-f` to open "fullscreen".

Answer (score 8):

Check

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Evince zoom
```

if it is not set to 1.0. See

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Evince
```

for all settings.

Comment: For higher Ubuntu versions the command is `gsettings get org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I wanted it to always open documents at 150% by default, so here's what I found out that worked for me (I'm using Evince v3.22.1):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom 1.5
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default sizing-mode free
```

(I got the hint for the default zoom setting from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/214163/163034)

Answer (score 3):

To start Evince maximized:

1. Install `devilspie` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/devilspie):

   `sudo apt install devilspie`
2. Create `~/.devilspie` folder and `evince.ds` file in that folder:

   `mkdir -p ~/.devilspie && touch ~/.devilspie/evince.ds`
3. Paste this code in `~/.devilspie/evince.ds` file:

   ```
   (if
       (is (application_name) "Document Viewer")
       (begin
          (maximize)
       )
   )
   ```
4. Add `devilspie` to **Startup Applications**
5. Reboot.

*devilspie' docs:*

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160415011438/http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie
- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/DevilsPie
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie

---

Alternative: [Devilspie2](https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/)

Comment: It should be available directly on evince, not achievable with an extra install... Also "Save Current Settings as Default" does not work...

Comment: Should be the accepted answer IMO, given that Evince doesn't provide such a setting in its defaults. Devil's Pie is the next best solution to achieved that (never heard of it before, by the way, so thanks for sharing this solution).

Comment: @ChennyStar totally agreed, I wasted so much time looking for solutions, this is the only one that worked! Thank you so much grisfer!

Answer (score 0):

To start Evince fullscreen as default, paste following command line :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default fullscreen true
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround **[Debian 9 with Xfce Desktop Environment (ver. 4.12)]**:

In the ***/usr/share/applications/evince.desktop*** file, comment out the existing `Exec=...` line and replace with:

```
Exec=sh -c '(sleep 0.6 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz)& evince "$@"' sh %U
```

FYI, while this will still open groups of files together (e.g. via clicking on a block of files in Thunar), only one of the thusly opened files will be so maximized...